# Exchange 2010 Multiple accounts in one mailbox

Tags: exchange-2010

I am looking for best practice or recommended ways of doing the following:

I have a user that has 2 email addresses, he accesses them via POP 3 and OWA. He need to be able to send as each of the addresses.

I do not want to create multiple AD accounts or mailboxes, but would like to be able to provide that visual separation.

Is this possible, I know using Outlook I am able to add multiple POP3 accounts and he can send from whichever he choose, but how to enable this is OWA, as well as on a mobile using POP3.

Thanks

Comment: are you tied to using pop3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of luck. 2010 still has 1AD account = 1 mailbox. With outlook2010 you now can add multiple exchange accounts to outlook (so no ned for pop3 etc- i have 3 open in my outlook at the moment - but every account still needs an AD account.

Comment: Ugh, OK thanks. Is there a better way to handle having multiple AD accounts with same name. Currently I am adding "(COMPANY NAME)" to end of last name to make it unique.